# Exclude a root folder from CakePHP app

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I am trying to exclude a first level directory from Cake (root folder app), as it should hold a different app.

/ holds the app

/development/ holds the tested version of the app

The directory structure:

Public folder

```
.htaccess [modified]
app
    .htaccess [unmodified]
    webroot
        .htaccess [unmodified]
        index.php [unmodified]
        ...
    ...
lib
    Cake
    ...
development
    app
        webroot
            index.php [dumps $_SERVER for test purposes]
```

So, my development structure still doesn't have an app inside (nor .htaccesses), just to test if my root .htaccess works.

This is my modification of the root .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/development.*
   RewriteRule (.*) - [L]

   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**What happens:**

/development/ shows the apache index of development folder

/development/app/ shows the apache index of app folder

/development/app/webroot shows the root app (request is captured in spite of the development url match).

/development/app/webroot SHOULD show me my /development/app/webroot/index.php file, right?

What the hell am I missing here?

Comment: wouldn't be easier to create a virtual host (maybe with a different port) to host your development site? and this virtual host would point to /development/app/webroot.. or maybe a subdomain

Comment: Usually, yes. But I need to test with a third party SOAP service, which uses SSL certificates installed on the main server, which is why I need to have it in a sub-directory. It is also a matter of resolving a common question. IMHO, any platform should be able to cohabit easily with other systems present on a site and not hog the root space.

Answer (score 3):

This turned out to be an oddball bug on my server.

The resulting `.htaccess` which works now is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/development(?:$|/)
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/development(?:$|/)
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

For reasons unknown to me, if I SSH'd to my user account and edited the .htaccess files through the command line, it wouldn't work!

When I uploaded the same files (via SFTP), it started working properly.

I am using cPanel (11.34.1) on CentOS (5.9).

Another example: if you wish to *"ignore"*  multiple sub-folders on a CakePHP installation, you can use this pattern:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   # /development, /version1.5 and /version1.8 directories
   # they all hold independent apps
   # or completely non-cake-related content

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:development|version1\.5|version1\.8)(?:$|/)
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:development|version1\.5|version1\.8)(?:$|/.*)
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Note that both `RewriteCond` instructions are identical.

Comment: The \. in the pattern is used to capture the actual dot. Without the \, dot means _any character_.

Comment: Put this snippet on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/dizyart/4733257), so you can favorite it for later. ;)