# RewriteRule to bypass CakePHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I am trying to setup my `.htaccess` file to send the user to a separate folder on my webspace unrelated to CakePHP. It is unrelated to the logic of the site and mostly for testing, deployment hooks etc. so CakePHP routing is not what I'm after.

I want users who go to `mysite.com/test` to access a `/test` folder at the public html level that my hosting gives me (instead of looking for a `TestsController`).

This is what I have in the root `.htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^test/?$ test/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

And yet entering `mysite.com/test` warns me

```
Error: TestController could not be found.
Error: Create the class TestController below in file: app/Controller/TestController.php
```

I thought `RewriteRules` work top down with the `[L]` ignoring subsequent lines. However this doesn't seem to be the case. Removing the `app/webroot` references is the only way I can access the `test/` folder (i.e ignoring CakePHP even exists).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As always when debugging rewriting: _TURN ON LOGGING!_ The `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` options allow to see in detail what is going on inside the rewriting module. Don't fly in the dark, open your eyes instead!

Comment: ah snap, `RewriteLog` has been deprecated (don't have access to the new way to do it)

Comment: whoops! duplicate of [Exclude a root folder from CakePHP app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751226/exclude-a-root-folder-from-cakephp-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) on your cake app rewrite rule.  Something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
```

Comment: Thank you @martymulligan, this worked. Added `RewriteCond` above each `RewriteRule`. But why exactly do I have to create a condition, am I wrong when I said _"I thought RewriteRules work top down with the [L] ignoring subsequent lines."_?

Comment: I believe you are right on that.  I'm thinking the problem could be with your rewrite rule for test.  I think I would write it like this:

`RewriteRule ^test/(.*) test/$1 [L]`